# Using XSLT how can I copy a specific XML subtree

Tags: xml, xslt

I've found a variety of answers around using xsl:copy (XSLT 1.0) properly, but they all seem to use the same `<xsl:template match="@*|node()">` which works fine for copying a whole document.  I'm struggling to match just a specific node whose sub-tree I'd like to copy and apply templates to.

For example, given this XML doc:

```
<MyXML>
  <a>
    <b>c</b>
  </a>
  <d>
    <e>f</e>
  </d>
  <g x="y">
    <foo bar="baz">
      <item name="aname">quux</item>
      <item name="bname">xyzzy</item>
    </foo>
  </g>
</MyXML>
```

And this stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item[@name='bname']/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(current(), 'y', 'Y')" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I'd like to do is copy only the element `foo` along with its attributes and child nodes, while at the same time applying that translation 'y'->'Y'.  The result I want is this:

```
<foo bar="baz">
  <item name="aname">quux</item>
  <item name="bname">xYzzY</item>
</foo>
```

I thought it might be as easy as changing `<xsl:template match="@*|node()">` to `<xsl:template match="//foo">` or `<xsl:template match="//foo/@*|//foo/node()">`.  I've been guessing at a variety of other permutations but I can't get the results I need.

Comment: The identity template (the one with the xsl:copy) doesn't only copy the whole document: it copies whatever node you throw at it. Specifically, the way you "throw a node at it" is by doing xsl:apply-templates selecting that node. So perhaps all that you're missing is an `<xsl:apply-templates select="//foo"/>` at the root template (`match="/"`) level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to handle the `foo` element, you could simply add a template that matches the root node and applies templates only to the node you want (thus removing all others):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="MyXML/g/foo"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item[@name='bname']/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., 'y', 'Y')" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that this assumes there will be at most one `foo` element - otherwise the result will not be a well-formed XML document.

Comment: I guess I don't understand how the matching works - is there an implied order of all the xsl:template declarations?  Is there some way to illustrate how all three "expand" to work together?  My intuition makes me think each declaration works in serial with the one above it, is this wrong?

Comment: I also don't understand why the additional declaration was necessary with the match at the root ("/") level, and why I couldn't make do with just the two xsl:template declarations.

Comment: @Matt By default, [XSLT processing](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#section-Processing-Model) starts at the root node and progresses downward from there - unless your stylesheet intervenes. Keep in mind that there are also [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#built-in-rule) that will be applied unless you override them. In this case, you would end up with the text nodes of `b` and `e` being copied to the output tree, if these elements were left to be processes by them.